# Добавление/удаление комментариев в Pdf

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, pdf, frontend

Нужно реализовать возможность открытия Pdf документов из проекта и добавления комментариев к тексту в нем или выделения текста.
Есть ли какие-нибудь готовые реализации или JavaScript библиотеки для решения данного задания?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[iTextSharp](http://itextpdf.com/)
Библиотека iText позволяет создавать и манипулировать PDF документами. Она позволяет разработчикам совершенствовать веб и прикладные приложения с помощью динамической генерации и/или манипуляции над PDF документами.

Разработчики могут использовать iText для:

- Передачи PDF в браузер
- Генерировать динамические документы из XML файлов или базы данных
- Использовать много интерактивных возможностей PDF
- Добавлять закладки, число страниц, водяные знаки и т.д.
- Разделять, объединять и манипулировать PDF страницами
- Автоматизация заполнения PDF форм
- Добавлять цифровую подпись в PDF файл

iText доступен для двух языков: Java и C#.